# Select value from state in NGXS by passing it a parameter

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngxs

I have a state which contains JSON as below:

```
{id: "1", name: "ig1", description: "ig 11"}
{id: "5", name: "hhh", description: "hhh"}
{id: "6", name: "ggg", description: "hhh"}
```

I need to select data for id  = 1 from the state array

How can this be done using NGXS state selector

And how can we access it in component?

---

I have below content in state

recipes

```
0 : {id: "3", name: "Cake", image: "index.jpg", description: "Lorem Ipsum is 
simply dummy text of the printing a…ldus PageMaker including versions of 
Lorem Ipsum.", ingredients: "ig 1-1kg,ig 123-4kg"}
1 : {id: "16", name: "gfdg", image: "Chrysanthemum.jpg", description: 
"fhfgh", 
ingredients: "gdfg-4sfhs,ig 1-1kg"}
2 : {id: "17", name: "hfgh", image: "Jellyfish.jpg", description: "ghgfh", 
ingredients: "ig 123-5kg,ig 1-3kg"}
3 :{id: "18", name: "hgj", image: "Koala.jpg", description: "ghjhgj", 
 ingredients: "gdfg-5sfhs"}
```

I want to get data in state for index 1, i.e. {id: "16", name: "gfdg", image: "Chrysanthemum.jpg", description: "fhfgh", ingredients: "gdfg-4sfhs,ig 1-1kg"}

As per your reply I have added below code

In component:

```
import { RecipeState } from '../../state/recipe.state';
edit_details :  Observable<string[]>;

editRecipepopup( id ) {
this.edit_details = this.store.select(RecipeState.findById).pipe(map(filterFn 
=> filterFn(id)));
console.log("edit=>",this.edit_details);
}
```

In state:

```
@Selector()
static findById(state: string[]) {
return (id: string) => { //<--- Return a function from select
    console.log("id=>"+id);
   return state.filter(s => s.indexOf(id) > -1);
};
}
```

But I do not get the data. Also my id is not logged in console

Comment: @who will give negative quote. can you please mention  reason. if you give negative then give the answer

Comment: I'm not one of those who down voted, but I would guess that it is because you haven't included any of your code to show how you have tried to solve the problem yourself - the best questions show what you've tried, and ask for help where you can't make it work yourself. That may lead to a totally different solution than what you were trying, or it might be a simple tweak to what you posted, but without even that, most people won't bother to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go , this is how you can query your state :

**In your State file :**

```
@Selector() 
static getIndexed(state: any[]) {
    return (index: number) => { //<--- Return a function from select
        return state[index];
    };
}
```

**From Your Component :**

```
this.store.select(YourState.getIndexed).pipe(map(filterFn => filterFn(YOUR_INDEX)));
```

---

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngxs-select)** ( And For More Detail : **[Do Read](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/concepts/select#memoized-selectors-with-arguments)** )

Comment: editRecipepopup( id ) {
     this.editdisplay='block';
     this.editclass='show';
     this.editdetails = this.store.select(RecipeState.getIndexed).pipe(map(filterFn => filterFn(id)));
     console.log("details=>",this.editdetails);  }

In console I get:
details=> t {_isScalar: false, source: t, operator: t}

Comment: it will always return observable , please check updated answer , last part code

Comment: @Abhijit , I have also attached the demo , please have a look , I think that clear all your doubts.

Comment: @Abhijit , have you tried this one ? please upvote or accpet the answer if its helpful to you.